# Salesforce PageBlockTable Render an Item's Grandparent

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to display the grandparent of a custom Salesforce Object in a pageblocktable in a Visualforce page.

I can display the parent as expected ie:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Related Item Parent">
    <apex:outputField id="ItemParent" value="{!item.Parent__c}" />
</apex:column>
```

works great and gives me a nice table with a 'Related Item Parent' column that is linked to the Item parent exactly as I wanted.

but when I try to go up a further level, the Visualforce Page editor tells me

> Could not resolve the entity from  value binding
>   '{!item.Parent_*c.Parent*_c}'.  can only be used
>   with SObject fields.

Is there anyway that this can be made to work?  I'm a bit stuck!!

Below is the complete listing for my pageBlockTable , which works correctly if the Related Item Grandparent column is removed.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="RelatedItems" value="{!contact.RelatedItems__r}" var="item">

    <apex:column headerValue="Related Item Name">
        <apex:outputField id="ItemName" value="{!item.Name}" />
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="Related Item Parent">
        <apex:outputField id="ItemParent" value="{!item.Parent__c}" />
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="Related Item Grandparent">
        <apex:outputField id="ItemGrandParent" value="{!item.Parent__c.Parent__c}" />
    </apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Really appreciate any help that anybody can provide.

Best regards

Pete

Comment: Have you tried `{!item.Parent__r.Parent__c}`?

Comment: Oh my god I am a prat! So obvious! Thanks ever so much for pointing it out!

Comment: JCD, could you add your comment as an official answer so that this question is not in the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing fields of relationship objects, you will want to use the `__r` suffix. For example, you could use `item.Parent__c` to refer to the Id of the parent record, but accessing any of the fields on that record would require something like `item.Parent__r.Name`.

In this instance, you're looking for `{!item.Parent__r.Parent__c}` (which will give you the Id of the grandparent), or even `{!item.Parent__r.Parent__r.Name}` (if you wish to access fields on the grandparent record).